# Rep extension methods unavailable when trying to extend it with implicit class?

Tags: scala, slick, implicit

I'm trying to extend a Slick `Rep` with a new method `=?=` supplied as an extension method via Scala's `implicit class`:

```
import slick.ast.TypedType
import slick.lifted.LiteralColumn
import slick.lifted.Rep

object RepExtensions {
  implicit class RichRep[T](rep: Rep[T]) {
    def =?=(rhs: Option[T])(implicit tt: TypedType[Boolean]): Rep[Boolean] =
      rhs.map(rep === _).getOrElse(LiteralColumn[Boolean](true))
  }
}
```

However in this case, for reasons I'm unable to identify, the method `===` is not visible to the compiler:

```
[error] /Users/.../RepExtensions.scala:10:19: value === is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[T]
[error]       rhs.map(rep === _).getOrElse(LiteralColumn[Boolean](true))
[error]
```

The `===` method is defined in Slick's `ColumnExtensionMethods` but I can't find any documentation explaining how to explicitly import that into scope - it certainly doesn't help to directly import that class itself. Indeed in the rest of my code where I'm dealing with `Rep` types, that `===` method seems to be freely available whenever I need it, without any special effort or explicit importing.

How can I get the `===` method into scope in this case?

Comment: Not sure, because I never used slick, but looking at the scaladoc, it seems that you need to make `T` a subclass of column: `implicit class RichRep[T <: Column[Boolean]]`. And if that does not help, then try _also_ swapping the arguments in the comparison: `.map(_ === rep)`

Comment: :/ Unfortunately, no. I believe the Rep *is tied* to a Column, but the rep itself is of type `T`. It is only the output that's of type `Boolean`. And I'm certain I have the ordering of the `===` parameters correct - you always have the rep on the lefthand side since `===` is a method on the rep. But it feels like you're on to something here, since `===` is on *Column* ExtensionMethods, and not a *Rep* ExtensionMethod...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension methods are implemented for types via the implicit defs in `ExtensionMethodConversions` (see the bottom of [ExtensionMethods.scala](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/v3.3.3/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala)). That means, for `===` to be available, the implicit needs to apply to your type, `T`. As `T` is unconstrained, it doesn't match any of the implicit defs to bring `===` into scope.

One way to resolve that is to constrain `T` to match. For example:

```scala
import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._ // or whichever database you use

object RepExtensions {
  implicit class RichRep[T : BaseTypedType](rep: Rep[T]) {
    def =?=(rhs: Option[T]): Rep[Boolean] =
      rhs.map(rep === _).getOrElse(LiteralColumn[Boolean](true))
  }
}
```

The next step up from that is to require a `Shape`, as described: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014901/154248 -- but it doesn't look like you need that for this definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, modifying it to `implicit class RichRep[T : BaseTypedType]` does *not* resolve the compile error `value === is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[T]`.

Comment: Weird! Here's a compiling example: https://github.com/d6y/basetype-ext-so65601910 - is it possible you don't have the profile.api._ imported?

Comment: I definitely don't have that imported, but in the version `3.3.2` I am on it isn't available. Let me see if I can find the corollary for this version.

Comment: I updated my answer and added the JdbcProfile, but that's not a useful example. I'll update it to include a concrete database profile to avoid confusion there.